# Añadir y operar con valores numéricos en archivos .txt

Tags: python

Este es un ejemplo de lo que deseo hacer :

```
f=open ("personajes.txt","w", encoding= ("utf-8"))
llistapers =input()
f.writelines(llistapers)
f.close()
```

Sencillo y sin errores, todo bien hasta ahí.
El problema es cuando trato de hacer lo mismo pero con valores numéricos.
Me salta el error, y no me acepta números.
Tengo el phyton 3.8.1
¿Tienen alguna idea del problema y solución?

Comment: Que error te salta? Ami me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Bueno, actualmente no me salta error, pero basicamente no funciona. No hace absolutamente nada.

Comment: Es que no te va a mostrar nada, pero te creara un archivo personajes.txt en el `path` que estas ejecutando el script basicamente.

Answer (score 0):

Debería saber la función exacta del código, y tampoco es que sea experto, pero quizás el problema reside en que los números que introduzcas serán strings
Prueba esto aunque tampoco estoy muy seguro:

```
f = open("tuArchivo.txt", "a")
#pongo a porque en write se borra el contenido del archivo
#En caso de que quieras no solo añadir luego buscaré otra forma

Var = str(input("Pon lo que quieras"))
f.write(Var)
f.close
```

Prueba esto, de todas formas luego lo intentaré solucionar en mi ordenador (estoy fuera)

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, revisar [answer], saludos.

Answer (score -1):

No se cual es exactamente el problema porque no hay un caso de prueba ni resultados de los mismos, pero al ser un archivo de texto, si quieres almacenar un numero, este dato debe ser un `str` y no un `int` o un `float`.

La funcion `input` siempre retorna un `str` por lo que sin importar lo que ingreses, debería de estar generando un arhivo `personajes.txt` con la información ingresada...

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, revisar [answer], saludos.